# Build data using dictionary

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I am new to python and i am still learning how it all works. Its been just a week since i started.
I am trying to code a program which does this:

1. Reads 4 columns from a file (ref input file above)
2. Get date, day and count from the file
3. And construct an dictionary to represent date day and count.

basically i wanted to represent the data in something like below and I am stucked in the syntax.

```
{
 "xyz" : 
    {"Sunday" :     {
                "20180101" : 72326, 
                "20180108" : 71120
                }
    "Monday" :                  {
                "20171225" : 51954, 
                "20180102" : 51954
                }
    }       
}
```

```
INPUT FILE:
DateDay             value       count   floatex
20171225Monday   |    270613|     51954|11.41|
20171226Tuesday  |    133579|     46126|12.01|
20171227Wednesday|    630613|     71954|11.41|
20171228Thursday |    253779|     96126|12.01|
20171229Friday   |    688613|     71054|11.41|
20171230Saturday |    633779|     66126|12.01|
20180101Sunday   |    633779|     72326|12.01|
20180102Monday   |    630613|     91954|11.41|
20180103Tuesday  |    538779|     73326|12.01|
20180104Wednesday|    630613|     61954|11.41|
20180105Thursday |    393379|     75146|12.01|
20180106Friday   |    130613|     51954|11.41|
20180107Saturday |   2643329|     70126|12.01|
20180108Sunday   |    863979|     71120|12.01|
```

**This is what i Have but its far from what i want:** Infact its throwing error now.. But that is not my question. Basically i am trying to understand how do i create the nested dictionary based on the input data

```
def buildInputDataDictionary(file, ind):
dateCount = {}
dateDay = {}

#dictData = {}
#   dateCount[dictData] = {}
with open(file) as f:
    for line in f:
        items = line.split("|")
        date=items[0].strip()[0:8]          ##strip spaces and substring to get only the date
        count= items[2].strip()
        day= items[0].strip()[8:]   
        dateCount[date] = count
        dateDay[date] = day
        dictData = {}
        dictData[date] = {}
        dictData [ind][date] = count

return dateCount,dateDay,dictData

dc,dd, di= buildInputDataDictionary(autoInqRhf, "xyz")          

print dd
print dc
print di
```

Comment: How do you run the script? I copied the input file text to a file, but I still get `NameError: name 'autoInqRhf' is not defined`. But if I change `autoInqRhf` to the file name, I get `IndexError: list index out of range`, is that the same error you get?

Comment: Here's a possible working solution with demo: https://repl.it/@downshift/HeartfeltDryKiskadee

Answer (score 0):

In your current script you reset the dictionary in each for loop. You only need to initiate it once outside the loop. When adding nested data you have to make sure, that all keys above the one you want to enter already exists. You can do this like this

```
#initate dictionary with your identifier as first object
dictData = {ind: dict()}

with open(file) as f:
    for line in f:
        # extact your data (haven't tested your code)
        items = line.split("|")
        day = items[0].strip()[0:8]
        date = items[0].strip()[0:8]
        count = items[2].strip()

        # add days
        if not day in dictData[ind].keys():
            dictData[ind][day] = dict()

        dictData[ind][day][date] = count
```